# Flood lighting malfunction

Tags: lighting

I live in a seniors condo association which was not well lighted.  Three years ago we installed approximately 40 Defiant motion security light, LED 180 degree, motion sensor units. I set them to dusk to dawn.  They have worked great, solved the lighting issues.
Recently, so far, three started to fail to come on at dusk.  One will come on by turning off and on the line switch and then go off after a period of time, one will come on when sensing motion then go dark, the other doesn’t come on but turns on at the line switch.
All three are properly set and I have done all the listed troubleshooting.  There are no line switch or power issues.
What am I confronted with?

Comment: did someone (no name) adjusted the time stay on ?

Comment: are those outdoor or indoor

Comment: The sensors most often used in dusk to dawn applications (CDS)actually have a memory effect. If the sun shines directly on them, they can wander "up" over time, thinking it's brighter than it is, which might be enough to keep them dark after dusk. Some other failures might have them come on early and turn off before dusk. Cleaning and drying them might help. The one I think for sure need replaced is the one that still senses motion but doesn't light at night (if it's set to do night light).

Comment: I don’t know how to say this nicely, but I’d never install Defiant brand. I regard it as junk. I’m a little impressed that only 3 out of 40 have failed.

Comment: Someone must have screwed up on the "parts that fail shortly after warranty" on 37 of the 40? Wait 6 months, the rest might catch up on failing, too..

Answer (score 1):

The `Defiant motion security light, LED 180 degree` comes with 2 Years warranty only. So you are out of luck. They are also Made in China, so the quality is questionable.

Disclosure: I am a senior so following is not derogative.
It is possible that some retired Electrician (or other) was playing with adjustments. So check those again. Even the light adjustment, one light can shine into other light and prevent the dusk till down function that way. A simple test is to put a pice of tape over the dusk/dawn sensor to simulate dusk and see if they come and stay on for the selected time.

After all it could be those are just simply failing after the warranty has expired.

[image: dusk till dawn]